# SpriteBatch.Begin and .End duplication

Tags: xna

If i have a class where it display font and images that contains its own draw function that has SpriteBatch.Being and .End

And i have another function that iterates draw function 1000 of times!
My question is that will those 2 lines of code slow down the performance:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Where the alternative is to have another class that manages the draw function without repeating those 2 lines of codes 1000s of times.

Comment: I've always done it by having another class handle it and only calling those 2 lines one time.  But someone else might be able to give better insight about what those 2 lines do under the hood, but I predict not repeating them will be ideal.

Comment: Think of SpriteBatch.Begin as the beginning of a process to create a collection (a batch) of sprites to draw. Every time you call SpriteBatch.Draw, it doesn't draw it at that time, it merely adds it to that collection you're making. When you finally call SpriteBatch.End, it's like telling Xna "ok, I'm done adding to that collection, send all those sprites to the GPU and draw them all in one stream". So, yeah, the fewer SB.Begin/SB.End calls the better the perf.

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel G and @RaZeR RawByte have a point. But lets say you want to draw your (lets say) ships on map with neon effect, and all the bullets pixelarated. That means you'll have 2 types of `SpriteBatch.Start()`. It's better to draw those 2 classes separately inside the class in witch they'll be used (lets say Level.cs).You'll most likely have just 1 instance of `Level.cs`.
So, instead of having

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch sp)
{
    SpriteBatch.Begin(*whatever effect you want*);
    SpriteBatch.Draw(*draw however you want*);
    SpriteBatch.End();
}
```

In every instance of `Ship.cs` and `Bullet.cs`, have them have functions like this:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch sp)
{ 
    SpriteBatch.Draw(*draw however you want*); 
}
```

And in Level's function `Draw(SpriteBatch sp)` put

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch sp)
{
    // Draw all ships
    SpriteBatch.Begin(*whatever effects you want for ships*);
    foreach(Ship s in shipList)
        s.Draw(sp);
    SpriteBatch.End();

    // Draw all bullets
    SpriteBatch.Begin(*whatever effects you want for bullets*);
    foreach(Bullet b in bulletList)
        b.Draw(sp);
    SpriteBatch.End();
}
```

And in `Game1.cs`, when drawing level, simply send it the `spriteBatch` variable, like this: `myLevel.Draw(spriteBatch);`, without calling `spriteBatch.Begin()` in `Draw` of `Game1.cs`

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to call Begin and End for every draw call. SpriteBatch puts your draw calls into an queue, so your drawing code will be interpreted as fast as possible (you can sort sprites by their depth, or by texture, for example - SpriteBatch will do all the dirty work).
You should call Begin and End only when you begin and end all of your 2D drawing, or when you change SortMode, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Only call spritebatch begin and end if you are going to draw, but if your method that's drawing is inside a begin and end block, then you don't need it. I suggest making a "draw" method for your class, then in the Game1.Draw method you can call that method, instead of calling it inside a custom class. Game1.Draw is the place to call spritebatch.begin and end, not in a custom class. Hope this helps!